# Pros and cons of ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-studio

A new version of Android Studio was released.
In the version 2.3 there are some news. One of those is the new ConstraintLayout.
Which are pros and cons of ConstraintLayout?

Answer (score 1):

Pros:

1. You can develop highly complex interface, using constraint layout.
2. It reduces the nesting, thus overall improving the performance of your app.
3. It helps to be seamless across wide range of screen.

Cons:

1. Sometimes the result is not as expected as you want.It sometimes feel a little to track of all the all the constraint. It might get a little overwhelming for a new developer to understand the code.
2. Sometimes you might want to create another layout for landscape mode for adjusting the views and widgets as it may not be as you would want.